# Como capturos los datos pasados con `with` en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Almaceno datos en la siguiente function store:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $ids=$request->ids;
    $multa=$request->multa;
    $pronto_pago=$request->pronto_pago;
    $dia_multa=$request->dia_multa;
    $dia_pronto_pago=$request->dia_pronto_pago;;
    for($i=0; $i<count($ids); $i++){
        $dato=Detalles::find($ids[$i]);    
        $dato->multa=$multa[$i];
        $dato->estado="Cancelado";
        $dato->pronto_pago=$pronto_pago[$i];
        $dato->dia_pronto_pago=$dia_pronto_pago[$i];
        $dato->dia_multa=$dia_multa[$i];
        $dato->user_id=\Auth::user()->id;
        $dato->fecha_pago=Ca::now()->toDateString()." ".Ca::now()->toTimeString();
        $dato->save();
    }
    $notification = [
        'type' => 'success',
        'message' => "Los datos de pago se almacenaron correctamente",
    ];
    $title="Resumen de Pagos";
    return redirect()->route("caja.show",$request->id)->with('notification', $notification)->with("ids",$ids);
}
```

En la variable `$ids` estan los id de los meses cancelados los cuales envio a la function `show` con `with`, es caso es que no se como capturar los calores pasados en la funcion `show`:

```
public function show(Request $request,$id)
{
    $venta=Venta::with(["detalles"=>function($query){
                $query->orderBy("numero");
            },"cliente","terreno","multa","pronto"])->find($id);    
    $detalles=$venta->detalles;
    $cliente=$venta->cliente;
    $terreno=$venta->terreno;
    $multa=$venta->multa;
    $pronto=$venta->pronto;
    $mensaje="El codigo escrito no es valido";
    $title="Datos de Cobros";
    dd($request->ids);//trato de obtenerlos asi pero no funciona.
    $ids=null;
    return  view("caja.cobrar.show",compact("ids","title","codigo","venta","title","detalles","cliente","terreno","multa","pronto","mensaje"));    
}
```

> Como capturos los datos pasados con `with` en laravel?

Comment: Es mejor utilizar el `Compact` en laravel, es mas simple y sencillo y realiza la misma funcion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas `->with()` en un `redirect()`, esas "variables" se guardan en una [session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data), no es como cuando pasas las variables a una vista. Pensá que el `redirect()` recarga el sitio, una variable no sobrevive, por eso se guardan en una sesión.

Tenés 2 opciones:
1) Accedes desde `show()` a la sesión.
2) Pasás las variables como parámetros de la URL y accedes a los mismos mediante `$request`.

**Primera opción:**

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $notification = session('notification');
    $ids = session('ids');
}
```

**Segunda opción:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->route("caja.show", [$request->id, 'notification' => $notification, 'ids' => $ids]);
}

public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $notification = $request->notification; // o $request->input('notification')
    $ids = $request->ids; // o $request->input('ids')
}
```